# What is the use of Custom Data Source in Contact Builder Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, contactbuilder

In Marketing Cloud We can define Custom Data Source and assign data extension attributes to it, but is not clear what is the use case for that,

I mean, What is  going to happen if you associate a data extension already linked to contact attributes to a custom data source? [image].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently isn't one. I've heard rumours about connections to AWS/Google in future for example but nothing concrete. 
For now all it is useful for is categorising where there data comes from.
To be honest, I've never seen it used.